# Does every circle in $\mathbb{R^2}$ contain a point with rational coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it true that any circle in $\mathbb{R^2}$ contains a point with rational coordinates? what about any simple closed curve?

If it is, could you please help me with the proof?

Comment: Yes, $Q$ is dense un $R$

Comment: @FedePoncio I know that one. I also know that Q^2 is dense in R^2, but still don't know why that implies what I asked!

Comment: Do you require circles to have positive radius?

Comment: For arbitrary closed curves, no. You can easily make a rectangle frame such that for each straight line part, say a horizontal line, the $y$-coordinate is irrational.

Comment: @Fede Poncio: could you expand on how that answers the question? Is it easy to see that $ (x-\pi)^2 + (y-\pi)^2= e$ contains a rational point?

Comment: @CarlMummert how about simple closed curves? (editted)

Comment: @nra: the comment by  edm expresses the idea better

Comment: @FedePoncio : but $S^1$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$...

Comment: @nra I’m sorry, when I read “contains” I pictured an open ball. For circles it has been answered below. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Proof for @FedePoncio's interpretation of "contains":
1. The circle has finite radius.
2. You can slice it w/ a horiz. line & get 2 distinct real x-values.
3. Every point betw those 2 numbers is inside the circle.
4. There exists a rational number betw those 2 numbers (density of Q in R).
5. Make a vert. slice thru that rational x-value.
6. That hits the circle in 2 distinct points.
7. Every point betw those is also inside the circle.
8. There's a rational number betw those numbers (density of Q in R again).
9. Now we have a rational x-value & rational y-value inside the circle.
QED

Comment: @dreeves but that y-coordinate won’t necessarily be rational

Comment: @FedePoncio: The y-value in step 2 may not be but then in step 5 we do a vertical slice and find a rational y-value.

Answer (score 13):

No, consider $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$ there are continuum many $r$ giving disjoint circles, but only countably many rational points.

Comment: How would you go about proving that?
How can I find a bijection between disjoint circles in $R^2$ and say, R or a set with cardinality continuum?

Comment: $r$ is a real number, it is the bijection with positive reals.

Comment: The bijection is given to you already!  Each $r \in (0,\infty)$ defines a distinct circle.  There are continuum many points in any interval, including $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @nra: this is a simple cardinality argument. There is no surjection from $Q^2$ to R

Comment: yep, I see... :-D
thanks everyone...

Answer (score 13):

For circles, no. Pick any number $r$ with $r^2$ irrational. Then the circle $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$ does not have any rational solution, or else $r^2$ is rational.

For arbitrary closed curves, even more counterexamples exist. Pick a rectangle such that for each straight line part, say a horizontal line of the rectangle, the $y$-coordinate is irrational, while for vertical line, the $x$-coordinate is irrational.